# Loading external templates in react-templates during runtime?

Tags: reactjs, react-templates

How is it possible to load external templates from the server during runtime with [react-templates](https://github.com/wix/react-templates) (or other reacte template system)?

I can't find any doc's about it but noticed that some people mentioned it as answer in SO questions.

Or should I just implement it my self and use the function "dangerouslysetinnerhtml" to inject the html?

What I want to do?:
Store html/css snippets in xml (or json), that is produced/managed by a CMS and load these in a react app. It makes it very easy to change the html, or support different languages without changing the code and making a new deployment.
I have an app running that is doing exactly that, that I have made with Google GWT, and I want to do the same in the react app.

Comment: Which template system you're talking about? https://github.com/wix/react-templates ? There are many  template systems out there

Comment: Yes, the react-template system.